# GKE node may not include cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool label?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

can someone create nodes without node pool in GKE? I investigate cases on some clusters there are many nodes without label: cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool and don't understand from your documentation if its OK or wrong? how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

During creation process all the nodes have the label added automatically, and after node creation you are not allowed to change its values, please take a look to the below doc [1].

> You can't edit this VM instance because it's managed by a group. To edit this VM instance, first remove it from the group.

A node pool is a group of nodes within a cluster that all have the same configuration. Node pools use a NodeConfig specification. Each node in the pool has a Kubernetes node label, cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool, which has the node pool's name as its value.

All GKE node pools have labels with the following format:

```
cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: POOL_NAME
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-pools

Comment: the situation is I already found nodes without node pool label (cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool) and I trying to understand how it possible? is it OK? how someone can remove node from node pool?

Comment: Please make sure that the nodes you mention are part of a current GKE cluster and the nodes were not manually removed from the Managed Instance group that GKE handles.

Also would you mind to share the output from the below commands so we can gather more information?

```
$ gcloud compute instances list --filter="NOT metadata.items.value:cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool AND name:gke-"

$ gcloud compute instances list --filter="NOT metadata.items.value:cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool AND name:gke-" --format=yaml
```